# PHP/HTML to populate a text input with a value from database on load, but write the new value to DB without appearing in URL?

Tags: php, html

I have two little bits of code doing the work here:

HTML:

```
    <form action="http://mypage.php">
    <input type="text" name="AnswerArea" ID="AnswerArea" value="' . $this_answer . '" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Q" value="' . $NextQ . '" />
    <input type="hidden" name="P" value="' . $quest . '" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ref" value="' . $ref . '" /><br><br>
    <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next" />
    </form>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php if ($AStyle != 'None'){ 
    if(array_key_exists('AnswerArea', $_GET)) {
       include 'connection.php';
       $newanswer = $_GET['AnswerArea'];
       $newSQL = 'UPDATE answers SET Q' . $prev . '="' . $newanswer . '" WHERE strRef="' . $ref . '"';
       if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $newSQL)) {
           echo 'Successful, comment out when ready';
       } 
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    }

}
?>
```

The intention is that when submit is clicked the Q, P & ref values are in the URL and the new value of $this_answer is written to the database. However, the input submit and AnswerArea variables are appearing in there as well. I know you can't have GET and POST in the same form, so how should I go about doing this?

The AnswerArea variable could be longer than the permissible URL length so I want to avoid it getting passed as an address.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Add `method="POST"` to your `<form>` and in your php page use `$_POST`

Comment: As you said, GET and POST cannot be in the same form, so you need to use the POST here. However, if the value their value is required to be in the URL, use JavaScript to change the submit URL before submit

Comment: Thank you for the responses!
I do want to keep certain values in the URL, but I want to be able to remove the ones that don't actually do anything in the URL (they're only being stored as variables for DB writing). I think I'm going to have to use javascript to sort this out. I've come across strtok, would that work? How would I pass the URL from the form submit button to the js and then follow the new URL?